# Como achar um número dentro de uma lista HTML

Tags: c#, html, winforms, navegador-de-internet

Estou tentando achar o número que a pessoa escreveu na box, no document.getElementByID no site, porém não sei fazer em c#, ou tentei pelo menos:

```
private void btnvalidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (webrequestNumero.Document.GetElementById("Numero").InnerText.IndexOf(txtNumero.Text) == -1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O número está na lista");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("O número não está na lista");
            }
        }
```

Alguém poderia explicar oque há de errado no código?

Comment: Deve alterar para `!= -1` em vez de `== 1`

Comment: Só complementado o que o @dvd mencionou, veja como funciona o `IndexOf`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/k8b1470s(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por favor, Você teria um exemplo do fonte da página?

tem várias forma de você identificar se o texto esta ou não no site.

A box se encontra dentro de alguma tag, um exemplo TD ou TR
caso esteja, faça esse código abaixo!

> foreach (HtmlElement Html in WebBrowser.Document.Body.GetElementsByTagName("tr"))
>               {
>                   MessageBox.Show(Html2.InnerText);
>               }

ao fazer essa função o C# vai lhe mostrar uma msgbox informando o conteúdo da tag, ai caso você queira você pode fazer um If para identificar se o valor da box corresponde ao que você procura.

ou melhor
caso a box esteja em um input com a ID ou name você pode fazer desta outra forma

> string = WebBrowser.Documento.GetelementByID("BoxDoConteudo").innertext;

Como havia dito a inúmeras forma de você trazer o valor da box, caso esse exemplo tenha ajudado ficarei mto feliz, se não me informa qualquer duvida?

Atte!